# gnome-software: undefined symbol: gdk_wayland_display_set_startup_notification_id

Tags: software-center, wayland

When trying to launch gnome-software, I get the following error message:

```
gnome-software: symbol lookup error: gnome-software: undefined symbol:
                gdk_wayland_display_set_startup_notification_id
```

I guess something went wrong with some library.

Here is the huge `ldd` output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffff75ad000)
libappstream-glib.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libappstream-glib.so.8 (0x00007f0958821000)
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f09585fd000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f09583a9000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f0958093000)
libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f0957cf4000)
libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f0957af0000)
libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f09571fc000)
libgdk-3.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f0956f18000)
libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f0956cf2000)
libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f09569d5000)
libjson-glib-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjson-glib-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f09567ae000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f0956410000)
libsecret-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsecret-1.so.0 (0x00007f09561c0000)
libsoup-2.4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoup-2.4.so.1 (0x00007f0955ecd000)
libpackagekit-glib2.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpackagekit-glib2.so.18 (0x00007f0955c71000)
libgnome-desktop-3.so.17 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-desktop-3.so.17 (0x00007f0955a36000)
libgspell-1.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgspell-1.so.1 (0x00007f0955812000)
libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0 (0x00007f09555f6000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f09553d7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0954fe6000)
libarchive.so.13 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libarchive.so.13 (0x00007f0954d37000)
libgcab-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcab-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f0954b25000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f095491e000)
libyaml-0.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2 (0x00007f0954700000)
libstemmer.so.0d => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstemmer.so.0d (0x00007f09544af000)
libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f09542a7000)
libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f0954035000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f0953e18000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f0953bf0000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f09539d5000)
libmount.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 (0x00007f0953781000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f095357d000)
libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f095334c000)
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f0953136000)
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f0952f29000)
libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f0952cdc000)
libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f0952ad3000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f095288e000)
libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f095267e000)
libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f0952478000)
libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f0952140000)
libepoxy.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007f0951e3f000)
libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f0951c3c000)
libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f0951a31000)
libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f0951827000)
libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f0951624000)
libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f0951421000)
libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f09511e2000)
libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f0950fda000)
libwayland-egl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f0950dd8000)
libwayland-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f0950bc9000)
libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f09509b7000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f09507af000)
libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f095050a000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f0950256000)
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f0950024000)
libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f094fe21000)
libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f094fbf9000)
libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f094f9ec000)
libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f094f7e2000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0958d67000)
libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f094f4c7000)
libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f094f106000)
libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f094ee5a000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f094ec0f000)
libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f094e9f1000)
libseccomp.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libseccomp.so.2 (0x00007f094e7ac000)
libenchant.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libenchant.so.1 (0x00007f094e5a0000)
libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f094e31c000)
libnettle.so.6 => /usr/local/lib/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007f094e0e4000)
libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f094dedc000)
liblzo2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzo2.so.2 (0x00007f094dcba000)
liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f094da94000)
liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007f094d878000)
libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f094d668000)
libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f094d41b000)
libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f094d1ce000)
libatspi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007f094cf9e000)
libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f094cd00000)
libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f094caf7000)
libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f094c8c5000)
libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f094c6c1000)
libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f094c4bb000)
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f094c2a6000)
libicuuc.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.60 (0x00007f094beef000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f094bc19000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f094b9e7000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f094b7e3000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f094b5d8000)
libattr.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f094b3d3000)
libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f094b1a6000)
libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f094af9f000)
libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f094ad8a000)
libicudata.so.60 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.60 (0x00007f09491e1000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f0948e58000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0948c40000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f0948a3c000)
```

Comment: Why do you have a number of libs in /usr/local inc. libgtk & libgdk??

Comment: It's not me, gnome-software is linked to all this stuff! Above is output of: "ldd gnome-software". It seems, this soft is built with gtk+ so it also uses gdk. My question was: what the hell wayland does here and what is the reason of such fail.

Comment: No Ubuntu packages install to /usr/local. So those libgtk and libgdk libs were install by you in some fashion. Get rid of them, run a `sudo  ldconfig` & likely your problem will go away. What does  `apt-cache policy libgtk-3-0` produce? What does `ls -R /usr/local/lib` produce?

Comment: Hi Doug.  
1. I never put anything to /usr/local. Some soft installed from sources could do it with make install defaults.  
2. ldconfig - no change.  
3. apt-cache policy libgtk-3-0:    
libgtk-3-0:  
  Installed: 3.22.30-1ubuntu1  
  Candidate: 3.22.30-1ubuntu1  
  Version table:  
 *** 3.22.30-1ubuntu1 500  
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages  
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status   
4. ls -R /usr/local/lib output is more than 1,000 lines.  I do not know how to paste it here.

Comment: You could paste the ls output here, then post a link, https://paste.ubuntu.com/   You have, it seems, quite a bit  installed to /usr/local. If the only thing not working correctly is gnome-software then consider using synaptic package manager instead or possibly rebuilding gnome-software off of your libgtk, libgdk in /usr/local..

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xmdSBHnDm2/

Comment: Purge and install again with synaptic is the very thing i started with...

Comment: No, I meant use synaptic as your package manager & forget about gnome-software. You probably would of been better off building everything to /opt instead of /usr/local. Maybe you could start gnome-software by preloading the .so's it's built to use, maybe not (  LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/.so  /path/to/.so /usr/bin/gnome-software. or instead of space separated maybe use  :  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

Comment: I use both. Some unknown soft it is better for me to try with gnome-software and immediately remove if it does not suit. Synaptic i use when i exactly know what i need. I also know that some soft gnome-software installs is out-of-date.
Even if i use gnome[...] not often, i can't be glad when some things seem to be broken (formerly evething has been working fine).